# How can I know if Windows 10 restarted because of some automatic Windows update?

Tags: windows-10, windows-update

Windows 10 restarted by itself. I wonder whether this is because of some automatic Windows update. How can I know if Windows 10 restarted because of some automatic Windows update?

Comment: It can help to add _which_ update you were doing...

Comment: @Hastur thanks, I did nothing. May have been an automatic Windows update.

Comment: It seem [it can](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/deployment/update/waas-restart#delay-automatic-reboot) _(Turn off auto-restart for updates during active hours prevents automatic restart during active hours._ if you do not turn off it can be turned on) and [here](https://answers.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/forum/all/disable-windows-10-automatic-restart-after-updates/16f1826d-a796-4de8-ac99-1d625420d265)

Comment: @Hastur thanks, I don't monitor that machine often, and the restart already happened.

Answer (score 4):

First check your ***Windows Update*** > ***Update History*** if you see an update the day it restarted.

You can find the info for restart reason in the Event Viewer, see this [How to View Previous Shutdown and Restart Details in Windows](https://www.sevenforums.com/tutorials/160855-shut-down-view-details-last-shutdown-computer.html) guide:

> 1. Press the <kbd>Windows</kbd> + <kbd>R</kbd> keys to open the *Run* dialog, type `eventvwr.msc`, and press <kbd>Enter</kbd>.
> 2. If prompted by UAC, then click/tap on Yes
> 3. In the left pane of *Event Viewer*, double click/tap on *Windows Logs* to expand it, click on *System* to select it, then right click on
>    *System*, and click/tap on *Filter Current Log*.
> 4. To see the dates and times of all user shut downs of the computer
>
>    A) In *Event sources*, click/tap on the drop down arrow and  check the `USER32` box.
>
>    B) In the *All Event IDs* field, type `1074`, then click/tap on *OK*.
>
>    C) This will give you a list of power off (shutdown) and restart
>    shutdown type of events at the top of the middle pane in Event Viewer.
>
>    D) You can scroll through these listed events to find the events
>    with power off as the shutdown type. You will notice the date and
>    time, and what user was responsible for shutting down the computer per
>    power off event listed.

Or better use the **[TurnedOnTimesView](http://www.nirsoft.net/utils/computer_turned_on_times.html)** from the awesome NirSoft which shows a **Shutdown Reason**.

Comment: Thanks, is there any event type  for updates? Or do I have to match the  date and time between update install and the restart event?

Comment: You don't need to match, in the restart event it says a **Reason** which would be something like *... for the following reason: Operating System: Service pack (Planned)* or  *for the following reason: Operating System: Upgrade (Planned)* or something like those

Comment: @FranckDernoncourt - "is there any event type for updates?" - Yes; But you can stop short of finding that event if you confirm an update was installed on the same day you suspect the system rebooted.

Comment: @Ramhound thanks, I'd prefer to confirm the causality of possible, date only may be a coincidence.

Comment: @FranckDernoncourt - So parse the Windows Update logs....

Answer (score 1):

*I wonder whether this is because of some automatic Windows update.*
So it seems...

It depends on if you have turned on or off the *Configure Automatic Updates* and the feature *auto-restart for updates during active hours*.

Reading [Delay automatic reboot](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/deployment/update/waas-restart#delay-automatic-reboot) section of the MicroSoft page on how to  *Manage device restarts after updates*, we learn that

> When Configure Automatic Updates is enabled in Group Policy, you can enable one of the following additional policies to delay an automatic reboot after update installation

> **Turn off auto-restart for updates during active hours** prevents automatic restart during active hours.

And of course you must have set up the *active hours*. This feature (the auto-restart) is active by default and may be not known/remembered by the average user.

If it's any consolation, consider that [you're not the only one](https://answers.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/forum/all/disable-windows-10-automatic-restart-after-updates/16f1826d-a796-4de8-ac99-1d625420d265) to be disoriented, surprised or unhappy with such behavior of the operating system.

> > Is there any REAL way to disable this cancer feature?

> Yes, of course. Setup active hours.